# Directory is empty or deleted;cannot delete the directory

Tags: webserver, hosting

Whenever i delete a file from the Linux Server it pops error message as :

[image: Error Message]

But at the same time if the directory is compressed and then if tried to delete it gets deleted.

> Why would that error pops out restricting user from deleting the
>   folder ?

I have already set full rights to the user.

Comment: Your question is missing every detail that is needed to answer it. First of all, is this a server you have set up on your own? Which distribution and version of that distribution is it running? How are you connecting? What is the purpose of the server, i.e. what software are you running on it for what purpose? How exactly did you compress a folder? Do you mean you created a compressed archive and deleted that archve or activated compression for the disk? If you are accesing via SSH: Please run `ls -la` in the folder in which you are trying to delete files.

Comment: this is a hosting server ..linux..im connectin via cpanel..its for a website..there is a option to compress in cpanel..

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm
What folder exactly are you trying to delete? It might be a vital folder for your webserver so there could be a reason you are not able to delete it.

Comment: In any case, if the method from the link fails, you could try establshing a secure remote shell connection via SSH: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_cpanel.htm
then after stting up a key pair continue with the links given on the bottom of the page. You should then read up on some basic stuff about unix permissions and how to set them from the command line as well: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm

Comment: thank you @zerweck tried your links for permission and ssl ,but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the solution,actually the server was exceeding the file quota alloted for it.Contacted the support for server they helped me to resolve the issue.Deleted trash and unused files in the server.This resolved my error.

Hope it help someone.